# WSO2 SSO with SAML 2 - Front End React.js (REDUX), SPRINGBOOT backend

Tags: reactjs, wso2, react-redux, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I need to integrate a client application written with **react** and **redux** (spring boot backend) with `WSO2 Single Sign-On (SAML 2.0) IDP`

Do I need to make use of few **node.js** based packages such as `"passport-saml"` etc to achieve single sign-on with `wso2 IDP`?

Appreciate if you could share your thoughts/expertise/any reference links.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I have exactly the same problem. How did you finally solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OpenSAML](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/Home)(no longer maintained though) or a similar Java SAML assertion library for this.

Passport-js is specifically designed to work with nodejs. One way u could make use of passportJs is by implementing the authentication and authorization business logic of the application as a NodeJs based micro-service. AFAIK WSO2 IS works perfectly with passport-js.